# oracle sql, change value to most common value

Tags: sql, oracle

The following script gives me delivery address information. But due to bad system set up over several years the NAME1 (address name) has several variations.
Is there a way I can change the NAME1 to show the most commonly used NAME1 but keep all of the other row information?

```
select ad.name1, 
       ad.town, 
       replace(ad.zip, ' ', '') zip, 
       ad.country, 
       (select sum(dp1.palette) 
          from oes_dpos dp1 
         where dp1.dheadnr = dh.dheadnr) count_pallet, 
       (select sum(dp2.delqty) 
          from oes_dpos dp2 
         where dp2.dheadnr = dh.dheadnr) del_units, 
       ((select sum(dp3.delqty) 
            from oes_dpos dp3 
           where dp3.dheadnr = dh.dheadnr) * sp.nrunits) del_discs 
  from oes_dhead dh, 
       oes_dpos dp, 
       oes_address ad, 
       oes_opos op, 
       SCM_PACKTYP sp 
 where dh.actshpdate >= '01-DEC-2013' 
   and dh.actshpdate - 1 < '30-NOV-2014' 
   and dh.shpfromloc = 'W' 
   and ad.key = dh.delnr 
   and ad.adr = dh.deladr 
   and dp.dheadnr = dh.dheadnr 
   and op.ordnr = dp.ordnr 
   and op.posnr = dp.posnr 
   and op.packtyp = sp.packtyp 
   and upper(ad.name1) not like '%SONY%' 
   and replace(ad.zip, ' ', '') = 'CO77DW'
```

Comment: Use a sub-query with a GROUP BY and look for the most common variation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to count the occurrences in the NAME1

Change it as follows

```
    select name1, count(name1) occurances, town, zip, country, count_palle,del_units,del_discs from (   
select ad.name1, 
   ad.town, 
   replace(ad.zip, ' ', '') zip, 
   ad.country, 
   (select sum(dp1.palette) 
      from oes_dpos dp1 
     where dp1.dheadnr = dh.dheadnr) count_pallet, 
   (select sum(dp2.delqty) 
      from oes_dpos dp2 
     where dp2.dheadnr = dh.dheadnr) del_units, 
   ((select sum(dp3.delqty) 
        from oes_dpos dp3 
       where dp3.dheadnr = dh.dheadnr) * sp.nrunits) del_discs 


from oes_dhead dh, 
       oes_dpos dp, 
       oes_address ad, 
       oes_opos op, 
       SCM_PACKTYP sp 
 where dh.actshpdate >= '01-DEC-2013' 
   and dh.actshpdate - 1 < '30-NOV-2014' 
   and dh.shpfromloc = 'W' 
   and ad.key = dh.delnr 
   and ad.adr = dh.deladr 
   and dp.dheadnr = dh.dheadnr 
   and op.ordnr = dp.ordnr 
   and op.posnr = dp.posnr 
   and op.packtyp = sp.packtyp 
   and upper(ad.name1) not like '%SONY%' 
   and replace(ad.zip, ' ', '') = 'CO77DW'
   )
   group by name1, town, zip, country, count_palle,del_units,del_discs
```

Remember I am using your query as a sub query since I do not have a clue how your DDL would look like.

You can even sort the result by the count.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to just replace `ad.name1` with

```
( SELECT name1 FROM 
  ( SELECT name1, COUNT(*) FROM oes_address GROUP BY name1 ORDER BY 2 DESC )
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1
)
```

This counts all occurences of name1 in the whole table, counts them and sorts by this count. So the most common name1 is in the first row. This row is selected.

Comment: Don't you need a condition/reference to the outer/main select? (This way all selected rows will have the same address/name1.)

Comment: Hi, reference would be the zip ... i.e. find the most common NAME1 where ZIP is the same.

Comment: Then you should probably edit your question to ask exactly that!!! "Most common Name1 where ZIP is the same"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
with names as(
select 'street 1' name1 from dual
union all
select 'str 1' from dual
union all
select 'str. 1' from dual
union all
select 'street 1' from dual
union all
select 'str. 1' from dual
union all
select 'str. 1' from dual
union all
select 'street 1' from dual
union all
select 'str 1' from dual
union all
select 'street 1' from dual
union all
select 'street 1' from dual
union all
select 'str 1' from dual
union all
select 'str 1' from dual
union all
select 'street 1' from dual
union all
select 'str 1' from dual
union all
select 'str 1' from dual
union all
select 'street 1' from dual
union all
select 'str 1' from dual
union all
select 'str 1' from dual)
select name1
from(
select name1
from names
group by name1
order by count(*) desc)
where rownum=1
```